# TanStack react table Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tanstack, react-table-v8

I want to use a React library so i tried looking for a library and saw this tanstack v8 table. I followed a tutorial on basic table but im getting some errors.

**//Parent  next component**

```
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import  BasicTable  from '../components/BasicTable'
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Vendor() {
  const [defaultData, setDefaultData] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const generateData = async() => {
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then((response) => setDefaultData(response.data))
    }
    generateData()
  }, [])

  const columns = [
    {
      id: 1,
      label: 'user ID',
      accessorKey: 'userID'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      label: 'id',
      assecorKey: 'id'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      label: 'body',
      accesorKey: 'body'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      label: 'title',
      assecorKey: 'title'
    },

  ]
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Vendor</h1>
      <BasicTable  data={defaultData} columns={columns}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The data that i'm getting from the api is these:

```
(100) [{0
: 
body
: 
"quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
id
: 
1
title
: 
"sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit"
userId
: 
1}]
```

**BasicTable component**

```
    import React from "react";
import {
  useReactTable,
  getCoreRowModel,
  flexRender,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { useMemo } from "react";

export default function BasicTable({ data, columns }) {
  const dataTable = useMemo(() => data);
  const table = useReactTable({
    dataTable,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  });
  return (
    <div>
      Basic table
      <div className="border-solid border-2 rounded mt-5">
        <table>
          {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                <th key={header.id}>
                  {flexRender(
                    header.column.columnDef.label,
                    header.getContext()
                  )}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
          <tbody>
            {table.getRowModel().rows.map(row => (
                <tr key={row.id}>
                    {row.getVisibleCells().map(cell => (
                        <td key={cell.id}>
                            {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                        </td>
                    ))}
                </tr>
            ))}
            <tr>
              <td>id</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm getting errors when i'm mapping the data rows. I'm new to using this library. I've already check and it seems that I'm getting the erros from the table.getRowModel()

Comment: I'm guessing you're seeing errors because `defaultData` is initially `null`. Wait for it to not be null before rendering the table.

Comment: I've changed it to an empty array: const [defaultData, setDefaultData] = useState([])
but i'm still getting the exact errors

Comment: Can you translate the errors to english?

Comment: The error says: " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length'). and it points out to line
 {table.getRowModel().rows.map(row => (

Answer (score 4):

`useReactTable` accepts an options object with the key `data`, but you're passing it as `dataTable`. Try:

```
 const table = useReactTable({
    data: dataTable,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  });
```

Comment: nice! i'm not OP but this worked for me...good catch

Comment: Hi, I've tried this one however its still not working for me :( can you help me? 
New error says: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <tr> in <table>

Comment: Hi, How did it work to you?

Answer (score 2):

Try using react useMemo  I struggle for days

```
 const data =  useMemo(() => defaultData,[])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that the data you are passing to the `BasicTable` is not undefined. You can fixed it by adding a check before passing the data to the `BasicTable` component.

```
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import  BasicTable  from '../components/BasicTable'
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Vendor() {
  const [defaultData, setDefaultData] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const generateData = () => {
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then((response) => setDefaultData(response.data))
    }
    generateData()
  }, [])

  const columns = [
    {
      id: 1,
      label: 'user ID',
      accessorKey: 'userID'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      label: 'id',
      assecorKey: 'id'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      label: 'body',
      accesorKey: 'body'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      label: 'title',
      assecorKey: 'title'
    },

  ]

  if (defaultData === undefined) {
    return <div>Loading ... </div>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Vendor</h1>
      <BasicTable  data={defaultData} columns={columns}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It would be better if you could implement the data fetching logic using the [TanStack/ReactQuery Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tanstack/react-query), as it has the `isLoading` state to check if data is already available.

An implementation example would be something like this:

```
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import  BasicTable  from '../components/BasicTable'
import axios from 'axios';

const columns = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: 'user ID',
    accessorKey: 'userID'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'id',
    assecorKey: 'id'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: 'body',
    accesorKey: 'body'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    label: 'title',
    assecorKey: 'title'
  },
]

export default function Vendor() {
  const {data: defaultData, isLoading} = useQuery({
    queryFn: () => {
      return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    }
  })

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading ... </div>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Vendor</h1>
      <BasicTable  data={defaultData} columns={columns}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried awaiting the API response? If that doesn't work, try initializing the table with mock data, to see if that works.

Comment: This in not an answer. It should be a comment instead

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV I don't have enough reputation to comment yet

Comment: I've already tried awaiting the API response but still getting same errors. I'm also giving the table a mock data which is from: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your data is not asyncronous. If the data is not yet ready, the table would throw this exception, while still working correctly. Render the table only if the array you're passing to the component is valid and has the right structure.